# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack: Learn Python The Hard Way Ex:41

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a script from Learn Python The Hard Way work.
From 6 errors I able to make it down to one error.
But this one error I can't solve even after trying for hours.
This is the error message:

> E:\PythonCode>python oop_test.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "oop_test.py", line 72, in 
>       question, answer = convert(snippet,phrase)[0]
>   ValueError: too many values to unpack

Here is the full source code:

```
import random
from urllib import urlopen
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"

WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
    "class %%%(%%%): ":
    "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)":
    "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
    "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
    "*** = %%%()":
    "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
    "***.***(@@@)":
    "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

#do they want to drill phrases first

PHRASE_FIRST = False

if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True

#load up the words from the website

for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())

def convert(snippet, phrase):
     class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]

     other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))

     results = []
     param_names = []

     for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        param_names.append(','.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

     for sentence in snippet, phrase:
         result = sentence[:]

     #fake class names
     for word in class_names:
        result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

     #fake other names
     for word in other_names:
        result  = result.replace("***", word, 1)

     #fake parameter lists
     for word in param_names:
        result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

     results.append(result)
     return results


try :
    while True : 
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        for snippet in snippets:
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snippet,phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question, answer = answer, question
            print question
            raw_input("> ")
            print "ANSWER: %s\n\n" % answer
except EOFError:
    print "\nBye"
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 39, you say:

```
results = []
```

After several manipulations, on line 61, you finally:

```
results.append(result)
return results
```

Therefore `results` can only ever have one member. Yet on line 72 (your error), you have:

```
question, answer = convert(snippet,phrase)
```

You can't unpack two items from a list holding only one, as @AdamSmith has correctly pointed out in comments by now. :)